# sudo traceroute -n . Not working

Tags: virtualbox, traceroute

I tried to run a traceroute command "sudo traceroute -n www.google.com" in my Ubuntu guest machine in an Oracle Virtual Box.
it displays this message

```
traceroute: invalid option -- 'n'
Try 'traceroute --help' or 'traceroute --usage' for more information.
```

Ubuntu version: 20.04.3 LTS
I installed traceroute : sudo apt-get install net-tools.I installed this and then ran the command sudo apt-get update

What could I be doing wrong? I checked it -n flag exists and it does.
And also whenever I try tracetrouting a site it always shows request timed out after the first hop
(this is a Virtual Machine).
What changes should I do?

Comment: Huh. When I do `traceroute -n www.google.com` (with or without `sudo`), it works fine. I'm using 20.04.3 LTS. What version of Ubuntu do you have installed? Also, how did you install traceroute? I did `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install traceroute`.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: What is the output of these commands: `dpkg -s traceroute`, `which traceroute`, and `whereis traceroute`? It's worth noting that `net-tools` doesn't contain traceroute. So I'm trying to figure out how you installed it

Comment: I checked all the commands which you told me to and I also ran `sudo apt-get install traceroute` and all say that traceroute is installed. The status when I ran `dpkg -s traceroute` shows `Package: traceroute Status: install ok installed`. So I think traceroute has been installed right.

Answer (score 2):

There are several forks of traceroute with different options. If you have more than one installed, the update-alternatives command will let you choose a default.

For example:

```
$ update-alternatives --display traceroute
traceroute - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/traceroute.db
  link currently points to /usr/bin/traceroute.db
  link traceroute is /usr/bin/traceroute
  slave traceroute.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/traceroute.1.gz
  slave traceroute.sbin is /usr/sbin/traceroute
/usr/bin/traceroute.db - priority 100
  slave traceroute.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/traceroute.db.1.gz
  slave traceroute.sbin: /usr/bin/traceroute.db
```

This is a version of traceroute that accepts the `-n` option.

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/traceroute.db
traceroute: /usr/bin/traceroute.db
```

It comes from the traceroute package (`apt-get install traceroute`) rather than the net-utils package.

If you have it installed, you can run it as traceroute.db or you can use

```
update-alternatives --configure traceroute
```

to pick the default version assigned to the traceroute command.

Comment: Thank you, my traceroute was working on the version which I installed through net-tools, but now I changed it to a newer one which you suggested. But what can I do about the request timed out problem. It never completes tracing it just shows request timed out ( I am using a VM) (network settings is : bridge adapter, even tried :NAT)?

Comment: That sounds like a routing problem, which is the kind of thing traceroute was designed to debug.  But you haven't given enough information to even consider that.  I suggest you ask a separate question about it and include output from traceroute,   `ip route` ; `ip addr`

Comment: I have raised another question relating this problem here is the [link](https://askubuntu.com/q/1389773/1565863). It would be great if you could solve it. Thank you.