# Traceroute shows request timeout message with stars

Tags: firewall, virtualbox-networking, traceroute

When I try to run traceroute in my Ubuntu Virtual Machine (Oracle) it only shows the first hop(self hop) and then it shows * * * and request timed out message

```
traceroute to www.amazon.in (108.158.254.76), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (192.168.1.1)  3.331 ms  3.301 ms  3.290 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

output form `ip route`

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s3 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.2 metric 100
```

I think it is using UDP protocol by default and my firewall might stop it. But shouldn't disabling the firewall work, I tried it but it still shows the same output. I know I can use traceroute -I will send packets using ICMP protocol but I have to use the traceroute command to get the response for my college work.
Is there any mistake in the network settings of my virtual machine (the network is NAT and also tried Bridge but both same results) or is there any way out of it?

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information here to determine the problem beyond your router isn't forwarding the traffic.

Possibilities include:

- The "router" isn't a router and does not forward packets.
- The router has a firewall that isn't passing your traffic
- The routing rules on the router don't include a path out to internet
- The next device beyond your router is firewalled and not accepting your traffic
- Your local IP address is in the private network range, and thus is not routable to internet.  Only a NAT based router can fix this, are you using one?

Considering that this is a VM inside a host, likely either you don't have a virtual router to forward the packets, or it is not configured correctly to connect the guest to the external network.  Sometimes this is intentional.